# How to align buttons next to text that should flow on 2 lines?

Tags: android, textview

So I want to have a title with 2 buttons next to it. These buttons should stick to the left next to the text, and when the text becomes too long, it should flow on 2 lines.

I was able to replicate this by giving the textView a maxwidth, but this causes the textview to take that maxwidth, even if it reflows on 2 lines. Therefore my buttons don't align next to the text anymore.

Like this:

[image]

How can I make my textView take the width it needs, not the one I tell it to use as maxWidth?

Comment: put the textview and the buttons in a horizontal linearlayout

Comment: You can use the Textview default drawableLeft and Right parameters I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes the perfectly working answer using ConstraintLayout (as I love this layout).

This is the code.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:maxWidth="300dp">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
            android:maxWidth="300dp" 
            android:text="Some layout is going to be created and whatever I do it won't cross the limit." 
            android:textSize="30sp" 
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" 
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" 
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" 
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:background="#365987" 
        android:layout_width="40dp" 
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/image" 
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/text" 
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image1" 
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:background="#e85f11" 
        android:layout_width="60dp" 
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image" 
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image" 
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Outputs:**

1. [image: Text1]
2. [image: Text2]
3. [image: Text3]
4. [image: Text4]
5. [image: Text5]
6. [image: Text5]

Whatever the text is, it will not cross the maxwidth. And with less width than maxwidth, it's width will be `wrap_content`.

Comment: Does this work when the text is `Some layoutis goingtobe`?

Comment: See #5: that is my issue, I want the images to stick to the text there.

Comment: @Vrwim I've checked it, tried many things and seen many posts, this is common in textview (unlike custom textview) that whenever a word with more length than available length comes, it shifts to next line and the available length becomes occupied even if it's blank. You should use some library for textview which will resize the text according to available space.

Comment: Also, not a single post is there on SO for it and so no conclusion. You should ask this as the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_male"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Male:"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_male"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_42sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_42sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/block_user" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_female"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_42sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_42sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/blocked_user" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_detail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is something Demo Content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

So you can just add content below the linear layout complete

[image]

I Hope it Helps you and you will get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingEnd="100dp"
            android:text="Simple textdfddfdf dfdfdfdfdf dfdf Sample  Text Sample Text" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/zero"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here, You have to pass android:paddingEnd="100dp". This you can manage from dimens.xml

I hope. This will help full

Answer (score -1):

You should use [`ConstraintLayout`](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1)

compile `'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`

Let's take an instance of that Planner part of the image.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    <!-- Other attributes -->

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width = "xxxdp"
    android:layout_height = "xxxdp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    <!-- Other attributes --> />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text"
    <!-- Other attributes --> />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image1"
    <!-- Other attributes --> />
```

Definition of Attributes used.

**layout_constraintTop_toTopOf** — Align the top of the desired view to the top of another.

**layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf** — Align the bottom of the desired view to the bottom of another.

**layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf** — Align the left of the desired view to the right of another.

Comment: And what do I place in the `xxxdp`? Wouldn't that cause my textview to always have the same size?

Comment: xxx means any number or `wrap_content`  or `match_parent`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this would solve the original problem. When text wraps to two lines, if you use maxWidth, imageView would not align to text, if you don't use maxWidth, textView would take up all the space.

Comment: That's why I've written, OtherAttributes in every Tag.

Comment: Wow, I tried the same thing, and it's working. 
Did you implement Constraint Layout correctly? 
It's not your Parent, but a child View Group which holds three Views.

Comment: Did you check the Link? 
I'm sure you didn't implement it correctly.